# Avoid jquery datetimepicker opening on page load

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using jquery date time picker and it is the first form field on my form and so when the page loads it automatically opens up the date time picker. I want it to open only on click. I tried adding a hidden field and doing autofocus on it to true. I also tried making the next field to focus instead of the date time picker but still the datetimepicker opens up on page load.

Comment: Could you post a working fiddle, or the main part of your code?

Comment: Do you use JQuery datetimepicker by XSDsoft: https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ and open page in IE?